# Want to skip content during code-first deployment

Tags: jss

I would like to avoid my content comrades from being unhappy and overwrite changes. Can I skip content from JSS package?

Good day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options for this:

1. Simply exclude content from your code-first manifest. You need to explicitly add content and routes in your manifest files ([example here](https://github.com/Sitecore/jss/blob/master/samples/advanced-sample-react/data/routes.sitecore.js)), so if you don't add them, there will be no content to import.
2. Use Sitecore security. The import process executes under a configured user context (`sitecore\jssimport` by default), and will skip any items which that user does not have write access to. Out of the box, JSS applies a [workflow](https://jss.sitecore.net/#/dev-workflows?id=content-workflow-and-developer-overwrite) to created content items which will prevent the import from overwriting items that have been edited, unless explicit access is given to allow overwrite again. Or, you can use the [security presets](https://jss.sitecore.net/#/dev-workflows?id=front-end-developer-vs-sitecore-developer-item-ownership) provided by JSS to deny write access to that user entirely, or configure the item security yourself, if you don't want content imported at all.

Comment: Additionally, the manifest generation script accepts an optional `excludeItems` parameter that will exclude route and content items from the generated manifest. There is also an `excludeMedia` parameter that will exclude media items from the generated manifest.